What does set theory has to say about non-existent objects?
Consider the sentence "objects that don't exist exist".
A set theoretical interpretation of that sentence, which dissipates the paradox, is that "the objects in question don't exist, but the set of the objects in question exist".
What does set theory allow to construct with regards to non-existent objects? That is, what does set theory do, in the mathematical universe, with the square triangle, the married bachelor, and the king of France?

All your concerned non-existent objects such as the square triangle, the married bachelor, and the current king of France are defined as the unique empty set ∅ embodying non-existence in most popular set theories such as ZF, which exists and satisfies your claimed sentence "objects that don't exist exist" in the sense of set theory. In a similar sense the entire cumulative hierarchy V of set theory could be said to be constructed from this empty set ∅ in a bottom-up fashion embodying (something) existence out of non-existence (nothing)...

@DoubleKnot Something out of nothing?! But everything has to have a cause. Especially in politics! Oh whippersnappers!

@DoubleKnot in set theory the empty set is a set. Thus, to say that it is "nothing" is not correct. In set theory everything is a set: thus, to ask "What has s t to say about things that are not sets?" is like asking "What has Greek philology to say about the Big Bang?"

A literal interpretation of that sentence is ∀ x ∈ ∅. ∃ y. x = y, which is vacuously true.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about maths, not philosophy.

Saying "The set containing the objects in question exists" (which refers to the empty set, and is slightly more precise than "the set of the objects in question exist") is not the same as "objects that don't exist exist" (which cannot be true).

hobbs's answer is correct as to why there isn't a problem here, but for similar questions, keep in mind that it is not permitted to construct sets using colloquial language about what they contain: there are specific rules regarding set construction that were chosen specifically to make it impossible to create internally inconsistent sets.

You may find Free Logic interesting: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free

Swiped from Oglaf (very NSFW webcomic in a D&Dish setting): QUESTION:"How many imaginary creatures do not cast a shadow?" ANSWER: " All of them."

@DoubleKnot The set of square triangles is the empty set. It is not the case that "a square triangle is the empty set". This applies to all the other examples. Likewise for objects that do exist, there is an important distinction between x and {x}, which was something that caused a lot of confusion amongst early set theorists.

@RobertFurber thanks for your clarification and you're absolutely right that the set of square triangles is the empty set {}, but square triangles are not the empty set per se. My point is that the empty set {} could be said to represent the unique same nothingness of every kind of set of non-existent concrete or abstract objects, and all math objects in the sense of foundational set theory are ultimately constructed from and reduced to this form of bracketed transcendental empty set {}...

Set theory has no more to do with that sort of thing than arithmetic does. Consider a math problem: "If you have three unicorns and four griffons, how many mythological creatures do you have?" The answer is seven. It doesn't matter that unicorns and griffons don't exist, because arithmetic has nothing to do with evaluating whether things exists. The same holds of set theory. Set theory has nothing to say about the existence or non-existence of urelements. The urelements are just taken as given.

Set theory on its own doesn't do anything. You can specify "the set of square triangles", and you can have that set interact with other sets in set-theoretic ways, and come up with theorems about square triangles that are true. For instance, if I take it as given that the square triangles are contained within the set of squares, I might also conclude that they're contained within the rectangles, rhombuses, quadrilaterals, regular polygons, etc. by the transitivity of the subset relation.
Of course, if you let your theorems come in contact with geometry, you might end up proving that there is some proposition that is true for every square triangle, and then, independently, proving that the same proposition is false for every square triangle. That's okay. That simply means that you've done a very good job of identifying the set in question: it's the empty set. All of the theorems you've proven are still true. Unfortunately, they're true in a rather boring way. All of the geometrical sets I mentioned earlier do contain the empty set as a subset, but then again every set contains the empty set.

I'm going to put this in programming abstraction terms rather than set theory terms, but I believe the argument holds:

Empty sets are still sets, no matter what type of data they theoretically could contain.
Types which have no instances are still types.
Empty sets of types with no instances are still empty sets,
and therefore sets.

(Not a citation but it must be mentioned: there is indeed a textbook entitled "The Joy Of Sets".)

PVS actually has a keyword NONEMPTY if you want to stipulate that there exists at least one instance of a type.

https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Joy_of_Sets/NFblBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 For the curious.

In the technical sense, sets are collections of elements, and naive set theory notoriously does not place constraints on the nature of the elements. For instance, sets might contain even themselves. This can lead to awkward situations like Russell's paradox. Russell's discovery led to various types of type theory (SEP) where restrictions to elements are built in to the systems. Both conceivable and imaginable abstract objects can be contained by sets, and are often defined as urelements.
In this circumstance, there is no reason that conceivable and fictional elements cannot be contained by sets. A conceivable abstract object (SEP) might be something like a circular square that can neither be imagined nor created in the physical world. Fictional objects like unicorns and dragons are imaginable, but alas, not part of the physical world either.
In these cases, the extension of the set simply needs to be specified by a series of tokens and types in the philosophical sense. For instance, the set of circular squares might contain a square with a radius of 1 (token), a square with a radius of 2 (token), green squares with any radius (type), etc. In a formal linguistic sense, a set is nothing more than a collection of linguistic tokens or strings that are generally stored in a list where the strings in question simply are references. To what they refer, in the most general context, absolutely does not matter.
